# Pass component to another component when dynamically creating them

Tags: angular

I have a component with `<ng-content></ng-content>` in it's template. I want to create this component programmatically, so that it has other component inside. Is it possible to do it with `ViewContainerRef` and `ComponentFactoryResolver`? Or any other way?

Basically, I want this, but created via code:

```
<component-1>
    <component-2></component-2>
</component-1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ViewContainerRef.createComponent()](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewContainerRef-class.html#!#createComponent-anchor) has a parameter `projectableNodes?: any[][],` that takes the nodes that should be passed to `<ng-content></ng-content>`

Comment: and is there a way to make bindings between parent and projectableNodes values?

Comment: No, there is in general no way of making bindings with dynamically inserted components. Usually a shared service is the way to go.